# 301 redirect to new page when the old one is deleted?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I deleted a forum from a subdirectory to a subdomain.  The one in the subdirectory was only like 2 weeks old, but one of the pages gets a lot of hits.  But, it no longer exists.  It now exists in the new subdomain.  Can I create a 301 redirect from the non existant page from the subdirectory to the existing duplicate page in the subdomain?

I tried:

```
redirect 301 /forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=45 http://forum.hollywoodnose.com/questions/126/alternative-ways-to-look-younger
```

But this doesn't work...  Like I said `/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=45` no longer exists.  But, it is the same as `http://forum.hollywoodnose.com/questions/126/alternative-ways-to-look-younger`.  `/forum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=45` is indexed though... How can I make this 301 redirect?  Thank you

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the page no longer exists that's one reason for the redirects, have you tried using the full path? And do you have any other re-writes going on either in `.htaccess` or within your forum or site app, kind of like how WordPress redirects to it's own 404?

Comment: [`Redirect` does only work with paths.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1421470/53114)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}  \bf=30\&t=45\b
RewriteRule   ^forum/viewtopic.php$ \
   http://forum.hollywoodnose.com/questions/126/alternative-ways-to-look-younger [R=301,L]
```